# Does panpsychism state that the mind exists in a different dimension?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology

Does panpsychism state that the mind exists in a different dimension? They seem to allude to the existence of a soul, and that the mind is a part of the fabric of reality, but are they saying that the mind exists in a different dimension? Because they seem to be saying that the brain isn't the only thing that produces the human consciousness.

Comment: See [Panpsychism](https://iep.utm.edu/panpsych/#H1): In a general sense, panpsychism may be defined as the view that all things possess mind, or some mind-like quality. Francesco Patrizi’s chief work, *New Philosophy of the Universe (1591)*, laid out a complete cosmological system, and introduced into the Western vocabulary the term “panpsychism.” Patrizi created a nine-level hierarchical system of being, with soul (*anima*) in the center. As such it permeated all levels, existing simultaneously at the level of the world-soul, the human soul, and the soul of inanimate things.

Comment: If *soul* is everywhere, then YES: the [human] brain isn't the only thing that produces consciousness.

Comment: About the "different dimension"... mind/soul is the reality. See Giordano Bruno: "All things, no matter how small and miniscule, have in them part of that spiritual substance… [F]or in all things there is spirit, and there is not the least corpuscle that does not contain within itself some portion that may animate it."

Comment: Who's "they"? There are panpsychists from different historical periods as well as contemporary ones. It will be helpful to know who you are referring to.

Answer (score 4):

I would not use the word 'dimension'. The problem with this word in this context is that it is used in a very precise mathematical way by physicists, and in this mathematical sense it would certainly not be the claim of sophisticated contemporary panpsychists that mind exists in a different dimension.

The clearest contemporary panpsychist statement that I am aware of is the line of Philip Goff and others, which draws from Bertrand Russell's suggestion that physics studies extrinsic structural relations of the world and its constituents, and that conscious experience seems in the case of ourselves (the only thing we know from the inside, as it were) to be our *intrinsic* nature, so maybe it is the intrinsic nature of everything else too. But it will never be found by physicists in some hidden dimension or whatever, because the whole methodological point of physics is to exclude this approach.